# Como pasar los valores de la posicion actual del usuario mediante el hook useMemo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que consta de un mapa que pone un marcador nada mas cargarse en la posición actual del usuario mediante geolocalizacion. Quiero hacerlo mediante el hook useMemo para cuando añada nuevas direcciones el mapa se centre en esas direcciones y si se actualiza el mapa no vaya de nuevo a la geolocalizacion. El problema es que al center del mapa no le llegan los valores de currentLatitude y currentLongitude, le llegan vacíos y me coloca el marcador en una posición incorrecta. Alguna idea de como solucionar esto? comparto codigo y un ejemplo en codesanbox.

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
  useRef
} from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, MarkerF } from "@react-google-maps/api";

type LatLngLiteral = google.maps.LatLngLiteral;

export default function App() {
  const [currentLatitude, setCurrentLatitude] = useState(Number);
  const [currentLongitude, setCurrentLongitude] = useState(Number);
  const mapRef = useRef<GoogleMap>();

  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "google-map-script",
    googleMapsApiKey: "AIzaSyB17U-TaHiXF-egDyrrCT_kejxz5ckXDNA"
  });

  const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null);

  const onLoad = useCallback((map) => (mapRef.current = map), []);

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setMap(null);
  }, []);
  const center = useMemo<LatLngLiteral>(
    () => ({ lat: currentLatitude, lng: currentLongitude }),
    []
  );

  console.log("soy lat:", currentLatitude, "soy lng:", currentLongitude);

  const containerStyle = {
    width: "600px",
    height: "500px"
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      console.log(position);
      setCurrentLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
      setCurrentLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      zoom={15}
      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
      center={center}
      onLoad={onLoad}
      onUnmount={onUnmount}
    >
      {console.log("soy el center", center)}
      <MarkerF position={{ lat: currentLatitude, lng: currentLongitude }} />
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-microservice-oiswii?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UseMemo` guarda valores independientemente de si se `rerenderiza` el elemento, la única forma de actualizarlo es a través de las dependencias. es decir, al hacer

```
const center = useMemo<LatLngLiteral>(
    () => ({ lat: currentLatitude, lng: currentLongitude }),
    []
  );
```

Le estás diciendo que una vez asignado nunca cambie, dado que tu dependencia está vacía (`[]`)

Tu `curentLatitude` y tu `currentLongitude` las actualizas cuando usas `useEffect` sin embargo ya no cambian en `useMemo`.

Para que funcione simplemente agrega ambos a las dependencias del `useMemo`

```
const center = useMemo<LatLngLiteral>(
    () => ({ lat: currentLatitude, lng: currentLongitude }),
    [currentLatitude, currentLongitude]
);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, estaba bloqueado y no lo veía.